# How can Perl's WWW::Mechanize expand HTML pages that add to themselves with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, firebug

As mentioned in a previous question, I'm coding a crawler for the QuakeLive website.
I've been using [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) to get the web content and this worked fine for all the pages except the one with matches. The problem is that I need to get all these kind of IDs:

```
<div id="ffa_c14065c8-d433-11df-a920-001a6433f796_50498929" class="areaMapC">
```

These are used to build specific matches URLs, but I simply can't.

I managed to see those IDs only via FireBug and no page downloader, parser, getter I tried was able to help here. All I can get is a simpler version of the page which code is the one you can see by "showing source code" in Firefox.

Since FireBug shows the IDs I can safely assume they are already loaded, but then I can't understand why nothing else gets them. It might have something to do with JavaScript.

You can find a page example [HERE](http://www.quakelive.com/#profile/matches/martianbuddy)

Comment: It's added to the DOM using JavaScript _after_ the page has been loaded, so retrieving the page source will only show you the container divs that haven't been filled with this data yet. FireBug monitors the site and keeps track of everything that happens even after the initial load, that's why it also sees this data. No idea how you can retrieve this though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get at the DOM containing those IDs you'll probably have to execute the javascript code on that site. I'm not aware of any libraries that'd allow you to do that, and then introspect the resulting DOM within perl, so just controlling an actual browser and later asking it for the DOM, or only parts of it, seems like a good way to go about this.

Various browsers provide ways to be controlled programatically. With a Mozilla based browser, such as Firefox, this could be as easy as loading [`mozrepl`](http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/) into the browser, opening a socket from perl space, sending a few lines of javascript code over to actually load that page, and then some more javascript code to give you the parts of the DOM you're interested in back. The result of that you could then parse with one of the many JSON modules on CPAN.

Alternatively, you could work through the javascript code executed on your page and figure out what it actually does, to then mimic that in your crawler.

Comment: [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) simplifies mozrepl, no need doing it the hard way.

Comment: This seems the best idea so far (paired with the Mechanize::Firefox comment). I'm currently trying it, if it works I'm definitely accepting this as answer. Thanks

Comment: It worked! I just had to make it wait for a particular class to appear and then get my data. Thanks again to both of you (I used Mechanize::Firefox)!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that mechanize mimics the networking layer of the browser but not the rendering or javascript execution layer.

Many folks use the web browser control provided by Microsoft.  This is a full instance of IE in a control that you can host in a WinForm, WPF or plain old Console app.  It allows you to, among other things, load the web page and run javascript as well as send and receive javascript commands.

Here's a reasonable intro into how to host a browser control: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-the-web-browser-control

Comment: Is it possible to implement that in Perl? Otherwise it's useless to me as I have to do this in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

A ton of data is sent over ajax requests. You need to account for that in your crawler somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are using AJAX. I can see where the requests are being sent using FireBug. You may need to either pick up on this by trying to parse and execute javasript that affects the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [WWW::HtmlUnit](http://search.cpan.org/~awwaiid/WWW-HtmlUnit-0.09/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm) - it loads and executes javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript). WWW::Mechanize doesn't do javascript. They're probably using javascript to change the page. You'll need a different approach.

Comment: I tried more approaches ("no page downloader, parser, getter I tried was able to help here"), but still no result.