# WWW::Mechanize work with Javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, web, mechanize

I used `WWW::Mechanize` for a site extracting application in Perl. I face the same issues where some web sites use Javascript. In my real application there's a `<a>` tag. The click function of `<a>` calls a Javascript.

I have this:

```
<a class="hLinkStyle16"
  onclick="return !checkIfSubmittedForm()"
  href="javascript:Litelogon()">Login with passwords
</a>
```

By using `WWW::Mechanize` can't we use `follow_link()` for that? I heard that `WWW::mechanize` does not support Javascript. I tried to use `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. I don't know how to handle Javascript in the above case.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Perl's WWW::Mechanize expand HTML pages that add to themselves with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900979/how-can-perls-wwwmechanize-expand-html-pages-that-add-to-themselves-with-java)

Answer (score 3):

With W::M::F, you don't handle JS, the browser does. Call the [`follow_link` method](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox#mech-follow_link-link-).

Comment: Thank you very much,I got the point what mentioned. I tried to install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox by using 'install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox' in cpan. It was done. But when i use the module in perl says Can't locate WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm. I'm facing little bit difficult to understand this issue

Comment: For your installation problem, [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide the whole output/log from that install command in cpan.

Comment: use cpanm to install instead of cpan <pre code>apt install cpanminus</pre> then <CODE>sudo cpanm WWW::Mechanize::Firefox</CODE>

Comment: @ophidion, you were attaching a comment to a seven year old answer. WWW::Mechanize::Firefox does not work anymore, see <https://github.com/bard/mozrepl>. It does not matter how you attempt to install it, it's not going to work.